# Can I get the black python code format tool to recognize what directory my code is in

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-black

I am trying to integrate the black python code formatting tool into my workflow.  As a test I have created a directory with the following structure.

```
hello
|_ pyproject.toml
|_ hello
    |_main.py
```

The pyproject.toml file has the following information in it.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "hello"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["my Name <name@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.rst"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.2.1"
flake8 = "^6.0.0"
mypy = "^1.0.0"
black = "^23.1.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 4 - Beta",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: MacOS",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
]

[tool.black]
line-length = 90
target-version = ['py38', 'py39', 'py310']
include = ['\.pyi?$', 'hello']
exclude = '''
/(
    \.eggs
  | \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
  # The following are specific to Black, you probably don't want those.
  | blib2to3
  | tests/data
  | profiling
)/
'''
```

As you can see, I include the name of my source code directory, `hello` in the `include` line.  From the uppermost `hello` durectory, if I type `black hello` it will look into the lowermost `hello` directory and format any code in that directory.  If I `cd` to the lowermost `hello` directory and type `black` or `black main.py` it will format the `main.py` code.  However, is there a way to use the `pyproject.toml` file to tell black where my source code is, such that from the upper most `hello` directory I can just type `black` and it will look into the lowermost `hello` directory without me explicitly pointing it there from command line.

Presently when I type `black` from the uppermost `hello` directory I get the message `Usage of black [OPTIONS] SRC ...  One of 'SRC' or 'code' is required`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--include`, `--exclude` and `--force-exclude` options are only applied during *automatic file discovery*, ie. when Black traverses the filesystem for files to format. This happens any time you pass it a folder. However, as you've discovered yourself, **Black still needs at least one path** to run, whether that's a file or folder.

There is this [issue on the GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/861) about allowing `SRC` to be specified in `pyproject.toml`. The general sentiment is it will not be supported for usability and safety reasons (TL;DR: let's not make `black` a footgun).

The point of those flags is so you can run `black .` from the root of your project and Black will discover the right files to format (and won't format anything you don't want it to format).

You can simply remove `hello` from the include configuration and Black will do the right thing (try adding the `--verbose` flag to see what how it's discovering files to format). Also, I see that you've taken the configuration used by Black itself to format itself. For the time being, you don't need more than this:

```ini
[tool.black]
line-length = 90
target-version = ['py310', 'py311']
```

You can always add more options / tweak it if you need more control.